# Pointwise Convergence of Continuous, Real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous, real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ converging pointwise to $f$ .

Prove that there is some closed sub-interval of $[0, 1]$ on which $f$ is bounded.

I'm struggling with a proof for this, any help will be appreciated (I can intuitively see why it is true).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and define
$$
A_N = \bigcap_{n, m \ge N} \{x \in [0, 1] : \left|f_n(x) - f_m(x)\right| \le \epsilon\}.
$$

Each $A_N$ is closed (why?). Since$\{f_n\}$ has a pointwise limit everywhere on $[0, 1]$, we have $\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty A_N = [0, 1]$. By the Baire category theorem, at least one $A_N$ (say $A_{N_0}$) must contain an interval $I$. Hence
$$
\forall x \in I, \forall n, m > N_0 : \left|f_n(x) - f_m(x)\right| \le \epsilon.
$$

By taking the pointwise limit as $m \to \infty$ and fixing $n$, we get
$$
\forall x \in I : \left|f(x) - f_n(x)\right| \le \epsilon.
$$

$f_n$ is continuous, hence bounded (say by $M$). It follows that
$$
\forall x \in I : \left|f(x)\right| \le M + \epsilon
$$

as desired.

Note: This proof is adapted from the proof of the [Baire-Osgood theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Baire-Osgood_Theorem). $f$ is a Baire class one function.

Comment: thanks for answering, is there a more elemental proof which doesnt require the baire category theorem.

Comment: @Raul The fact that we're considering a Baire class one function strongly suggests the Baire category theorem. I don't know if there is a more elementary proof.